# fetch data from database and showing it in a table using mouseover without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsp, plugins

I am developing an application of piechart(taking help from [here](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/)). Now I am building that on mouseover/hover to that table it will show an another table which contains the other column value[suppose tablename:widgetsold; column:Widget,Sales,Profit,Purchase,..] without refreshing the page(as i am using jsp).

here is jquery:   function init() {

```
// Get the canvas element in the page
canvas = document.getElementById('chart');

// Exit if the browser isn't canvas-capable
if ( typeof canvas.getContext === 'undefined' ) return;

// Initialise some properties of the canvas and chart
canvasWidth = canvas.width;
canvasHeight = canvas.height;
centreX = canvasWidth / 2;
centreY = canvasHeight / 2;
chartRadius = Math.min( canvasWidth, canvasHeight ) / 2 * ( chartSizePercent / 100 );

// Grab the data from the table,
// and assign click handlers to the table data cells

var currentRow = -1;
var currentCell = 0;

$('#chartData td').each( function() {
  currentCell++;
  if ( currentCell % 2 != 0 ) {
    currentRow++;
    chartData[currentRow] = [];
    chartData[currentRow]['label'] = $(this).text();
  } else {
   var value = parseFloat($(this).text());
   totalValue += value;
   value = value.toFixed(2);
   chartData[currentRow]['value'] = value;
  }

  // Store the slice index in this cell, and attach a click handler to it
  $(this).data( 'slice', currentRow );
  $(this).hover( handleTableClick );
  $(this).click( handleTableClick );

  // Extract and store the cell colour
  if ( rgb = $(this).css('color').match( /rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)/) ) {
    chartColours[currentRow] = [ rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3] ];
  } else if ( hex = $(this).css('color').match(/#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/) ) {
    chartColours[currentRow] = [ parseInt(hex[1],16) ,parseInt(hex[2],16), parseInt(hex[3], 16) ];
  } else {
    alert( "Error: Colour could not be determined! Please specify table colours using the format '#xxxxxx'" );
    return;
  }

} );

// Now compute and store the start and end angles of each slice in the chart data

var currentPos = 0; // The current position of the slice in the pie (from 0 to 1)

for ( var slice in chartData ) {
  chartData[slice]['startAngle'] = 2 * Math.PI * currentPos;
  chartData[slice]['endAngle'] = 2 * Math.PI * ( currentPos + ( chartData[slice]['value'] / totalValue ) );
  currentPos += chartData[slice]['value'] / totalValue;
}

// All ready! Now draw the pie chart, and add the click handler to it
drawChart();
$('#chart').click ( handleChartClick );
```

}

and my jsp page:

```
<body>
<% 
String s1= "A";
String s2= "B";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/apps","root","root");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql1="select count(case when device='"+s1+"' then 1 end) as A,count(case when device='"+s2+"' then 1 end) as B from user_management;";

ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);

System.out.println(sql1);
%>

<div id="container">

<div class="wideBox">
<h1>Chart</h1>
</div>

<canvas id="chart" width="500" height="440"></canvas>

<table id="chartData">

<% while(rs1.next()){ %>
<tr>
  <th>Team</th><th>Players</th>
 </tr>

<tr style="color: #0DA068">
  <td>A</td><td><%= rs1.getString(1)%></td>
</tr>

<tr style="color: #194E9C">
  <td>B</td><td><%= rs1.getString(2)%></td>
</tr>       
 <% } 

%>

</table>
</div>
</body>
```

I have gone through manysites and understand that with the help of AJAX,PHP it can be done,but I am using JSP.I want to implement show another table on mouseover to show related details of each row.

So any suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

Break up your problem in small parts. The mouseover part can be done using JavaScript. Write this, let it display some data (that you define in JS). When that part is done, you can update the JavaScript part containing the test data to actually get live data, using AJAX.

AJAX is a technique that can be used, not something that has to be defined in your serverside language. Any servlet returning data in a machine-readable format (hint: [JSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples)) can be called by a piece of JavaScript and voilá: AJAX.